# Tor router validation

Tags: relays, protocol

my question is how does Tor validate routers? There are some specifications that mention that there are "validated" nodes, which have a "valid" flag (e.g. https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt?id=ebb7d8701d000683ec7016176996f168dd10637b).

How does Tor determine whether a node is valid or not? I couldn't figure it out of that reference. 
If you have an answer, please also provide a reference.

Answer (score 2):

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt?id=ebb7d8701d000683ec7016176996f168dd10637b#n2085

```
"Valid" -- a router is 'Valid' if it is running a version of Tor not
known to be broken, and the directory authority has not blacklisted
it as suspicious.
```

Comment: it is actually a bit confising name for a flag "Valid", IMHO. I think it should be named as "Useable" - that makes sense a way more clearly